# How to stop/terminate confluent JDBC source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am running the confluent JDBC source connector to read from a DB table and publish to a Kafka Topic. The Connector is started by a Job-scheduler and I need to stop the connector after it has published all the rows from the DB table. Any idea how to stop it gracefully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the REST API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest) to pause (or delete) a connector

`PUT /connectors/:name/pause`

There is no "notification" to know if all records are loaded, though, so in the JDBC Source, you can also schedule the bulk mode with a long time delay (say a whole week), then schedule the connector deletion.

Comment: Does pause stop the connector?

Comment: @Gibbs It should

Answer (score 0):

to pause it, run this from a command shell (that has CURL installed):

```
curl -X PUT <host>:8083/connectors/<connector_name>/pause
```

to resume back again you use:

```
curl -X PUT <host>:8083/connectors/<connector_name>/resume
```

to see whether it's paused or not, use:

```
curl <host>:8083/connectors/<connector_name>/status | jq
```

the "jq" part makes it more readable.